# How to get to a tab bar from the embedded view?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, navigationcontroller

I have a tab bar controller in my application that has 4 tabs. One of them is supposed to display one of 2 scenes based on the response from the API: either an empty view if there is no data or a segmented control if there is data. 
Here are the storyboards with the setup:

[image: Tab bar storyboard]
[image: Views storyboard]

On both an empty view and a view with data I have a button that should "click" one of the buttons on a tab bar (switch to another tab).

For now this is what I'm doing:

Showing the view with data:

```
class EmptyTasksVC: ViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if(there_is_data){
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TaskTodoList", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TaskListSegmentedControl")

            let childNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            childNavigation.willMove(toParent: self)
            addChild(childNavigation)
            childNavigation.view.frame = view.frame
            view.addSubview(childNavigation.view)
            childNavigation.didMove(toParent: self)
         }
    }
}
```

Finding the tab bar on button click from view with data:

```
@objc func newTaskAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let viewController = self.findViewController()
    let tabBar = viewController?.parent?.parent?.parent?.parent?.parent as! UITabBarController
    tabBar.selectedIndex = 2
}
...

extension UIView {
    func findViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIViewController {
            return nextResponder
        } else if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIView {
            return nextResponder.findViewController()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to get to the button from empty view I have to remove 2 "parents" from the chain.

There MUST be a better way to do it... 
Is my architecture wrong? How can I get to the tab bar from the embedded view if I don't know how many views are on the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ViewController` already has a property `tabBarController` with description as

> // If the view controller has a tab bar controller as its ancestor,
>   return it. Returns nil otherwise.

so you can directly access the `TabBar` `Controller` your viewController is embedded in,

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: i dont think this will work for controllers embedded in Container views.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. For some reason I thought it will not be possible to access it if I'm not in the tabBarViewController. Thank you, kind sir!

Comment: @MartaPanuszewska Never mind, it’s part of the process. Keep working :)